# How to customize HTML 5 date picker

Tags: html, datepicker

I need to put a date picker in my application. I'm thinking of customizing the `HTML 5 datepicker`

```
<input class="form-control" type="date">
```

I need to change the down arrow to a calendar image. and also need to show the icon all the time. Not just on hover.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Bootstrap frameWork, Then It Will help you:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```